# Solr single query with AND and OR option

Tags: solr

[Sorry if it is a duplicate Question]

I wanted to extract results from solr which obeys multiple conditions on the same field, with both `AND` and `OR` operations in it. Is it possible to do something like this

```
q=_word:* AND _link:0 OR !_link:*
```

If I query this I am not getting any response. 
Can anyone help me to achieve what I want? If possible share a link, I searched for it but I am not able to find how to solve this.

Comment: Thanks everyone, i myself found the answers and it is working fine (_word:* AND !_link:*) OR  (_word:* AND _link:0) Thanks once again for your quicker responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(_word:* AND !_link:*) OR (_word:* AND _link:0)

This works